# Distribute a sum randomly across columns

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of length `n`. Let's say `n=3` so and the vector is `v=c(3,5,4)`.

I have a matrix of zeros with `n` rows and `m` columns. Let's say `m=5`

```
mymatrix <- matrix(rep(0, 3*5), nrow=3)
```

what I want to to is randomly distribute the values of `v` across columns, for each row. So in this example, the first row would sum to 3, the second row would sum to 5, and the third row would sum to 4. E.g. this would be one possible random assignment:

```
0   1   2   0   0
3   1   0   0   1
0   2   2   0   0
```

The sums of the rows are 3,5,4, which are the values of `v`.

How can I accomplish this? My thought was to start with

```
sapply(v, function(i){sample(1:m, i, replace=TRUE)})
```

and go from there but this gives me a list, since each result is of a different length, and I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

EDIT: the intention is no negative numbers, so `0 9 1 1 -8` summing to 3 would not be a valid row.

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr`:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

n <- 3
m <- 5
v <- c(3,5,4)
y <- sapply(v, function(i){sample(1:m, i, replace=TRUE)})

do_it <- function(x) {
  tmp <- tibble(
    index = x,
    cnt = 1
  ) %>% 
    group_by(index) %>% 
    summarise(cnt = sum(cnt))
  out <- rep(0, m)
  out[tmp$index] <- tmp$cnt
  return(out)
}

y %>%
  map(~do_it(.x)) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  matrix(nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `parts` from package `partitions` is the tool you need for your objective, i.e.,

```
library(partitions)
# define your custom function `f` to generate random combinations and positions, with row sum subject to the given value 
f <- function(k) replace(rep(0,ncol(mymatrix)),
                         sample(ncol(mymatrix),k),
                         as.data.frame.matrix(parts(k))[sample(k),sample(k,1)])
```

such that

```
set.seed(1)
M <- t(sapply(v, f))
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    3    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    4    0
[3,]    0    4    0    0    0
```